# How to set a class names to component object on ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

By example, have a list component when each item have a custom icon component and set it on properties. But, how to add a class name to object into the variable?:

```
const items = [
    { name: "Example", icon: <Foo /> }
];

return (
    <ListItems items={items} />
)
```

Now, from `ListItems` components, how to add a classname to icon object?

```
return (
    <div>
        {items.map((prop, key) => {
            {prop.icon}
            <span>{prop.name}</span>
        })}
    </div>
);
```

The ListItem is a component with own style, but need add classname to icon object, by example:

```
<[prop.icon] className={classes.foo} />
```

(but `<[prop.icon] />` is a invalid syntax).

Comment: Have you tried <{prop.icon} className={classes.foo} /> ... I have no idea if that will work. I normally achieve this effect with {children}.

Comment: `Line 65:30:  Parsing error: Unexpected token` `<{prop.icon} />`. Yes, with `{prop.icon}` without tag works fine, but, how to add the classnames to `prop.icon` without jsx tag or how to convert the object to a valid jsx tag.

Comment: So you are passing a component down, and you want to display that component in the child?

Comment: Need display the `{prop.icon}` component but with a specific class setted by the `ListItems` components. The icon is set from the main layout dinamicaly. The classnames styles is for `ListItems` not from main layout.

Comment: The `ListItems` is the sidebar component of the main admin panel layout, from main layout set the items with custom icons from `materials.io`, but need set the classnames of the each icon from the sidebar component to recycle component without styles dependencies from the main layout.

Comment: Glad you found an answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39226928/react-adding-class-to-children-components is similar too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if its the best solution, anyway you can have it a try

```
const items = [
    { name: "Example", icon: (props) => <Foo {...props} /> }
];

return (
    <ListItems items={items} />
)
```

```
return (
    <div>
        {links.map((prop, key) => {
            {prop.icon({className: classes.foo})}
            <span>{prop.name}</span>
        })}
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you might have to change your icon as a component instead a JSXElement:

```
icon: props => <Foo {...props} />
```

Then you can use it as a component normally:

```
const Icon = props.icon;
<Icon className="yourClassName" />
```